# video hosting and streaming

Tags: youtube, amazon-ec2, hosting, video-encoding

I have an account in the Amazon S3 where I upload files - among them video files. 
What I need to do next, is to show my clients a specific video, and I need something that support all kinds of encoding. Most of the time, the user uses a smartphone to watch the video, and I need some software to stream the video-file right into his/her smartphone - and no matter in which format the video file was uploaded, I need that the user will be able to watch it.

I saw some solutions such as Vimeo, Vzaar, etc. but I'm looking for something else - without too many limits on size and bandwidth, with a good API to upload the files into it, and with cross-platform ability to view the file.

Is there a solution in Youtube? in Amazon EC2? etc.?

Any other solution?

Thanks a lot,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

One solution for you is to use a conversion utility like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)
for your conversion needs. One format of course cannot support all end users (PC browsers, mobile browsers and so on), so you need to convert the originally uploaded file to multiple formats and render to the user what is best based on the device type which accesses it.

You can also look at Darwin streaming server and host it on Amazon or any other platform for that matter to suit your need

If you are looking for a solution directly from Amzon by uploading your files on S3 and stream it, then currently Amazon supports only Adobe server as its streaming server in production mode, so you are pretty much restricted to the formats that the streaming server supports. Still the ownus is on you to convert in to different formats.